# problem with rtl languages

Tags: crystal-reports

i have a problem when i use rtl fonts for my crystal reports. the problem occurs when i export my report to PDF.the pdf file shows all of latin word unmeaning (they are converted to square) for example: in crystal ==> www.tss-dev.com in PDF ==> every latin char convert to char(127)or small square

Comment: Sounds not like a font problem, but a unicode handling problem.

Comment: yes, you're right. itested it ,crystalreports has this problem but when give the CR file to CRviewr (.net) ,the CRviewr doesn't have any problem with and it shows all words correctly.
can you help me to know what happen in CrystalReportViewer(.net)?
tanx

Answer (score 1):

You can check "Reading Order" property of TextObject.
You can set it to "Right to Left", this will fix issue of showing RTL languages in report viewer.

You can check "Reading Order" property by clicking right on TextObject, move to Paragraph tab, you will get it.

Comment: tanx, i did. as Pavel said it has unicode handling problem. iwanna know about that.

Comment: @Maryam: 'iwanna know about that', what do you want to know? Is above solution works for you or not?

Comment: no it doesn't work for me. i wanna select a Farsi font (for example MITRA) CR can't show english word correctly By the font ,CR shows small squre instead of english word