# right to left string in crystal report

Tags: sql, sql-server, crystal-reports, right-to-left

Consider Below Query in SQL Server

[image]

below picture is result of this query in Crystal Reports.

[image]

as you can see the right part is exactly same as query result in sql server and left part is converted by a locked function to meet right to left property of Persian language.

I need to Obtain this Function.

Comment: Just a small off-topic note: always start your Unicode strings with `N` and do not rely that they work without `N`. Omitting `N` can cause you problems with some data – I already have that experience.

Comment: [Setting "Reading Order" property of TextObject to "Right to Left"](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3134004/2392157) – isn't that enough?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you have re-write you sql statement to be as follow:

```
  SELECT N'Your Text'
```

and in crystal report on your text object > right click > Format Object > Paragraph tab > Reading Order > Select Right to Left
as Image Below

[image]